# How to update an Atomic based on a condition?

Tags: java, concurrentmodification, atomicinteger

How to update an `AtomicInteger` if its current value is less than the given value? The idea is:

```
AtomicInteger ai = new AtomicInteger(0);
...
ai.update(threadInt); // this call happens concurrently
...
// inside AtomicInteger atomic operation
synchronized {
    if (ai.currentvalue < threadInt)
        ai.currentvalue = threadInt;
}
```

Comment: pls paste working code i.e. without any compilation error..

Comment: Your posted code snippet make no sense. You first update `ai` (whatever you mean with .update()) and after you check the value with the new one.

Comment: This is a good question and it makes perfect sense. For the criticism: It is impossible for the OP to write working code for this. If he did, he would need to know the answer, so he can only post pseudo-code.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you are using Java 8 you can use one of the new update methods in `AtomicInteger`, which you can pass a lambda expression. For example:

```
AtomicInteger ai = new AtomicInteger(0);

int threadInt = ...

// Update ai atomically, but only if the current value is less than threadInt
ai.updateAndGet(value -> value < threadInt ? threadInt : value);
```

Answer (score 6):

***If I didn't have Java 8***, I would probably create a utility method, something like:

```
public static boolean setIfIncreases(AtomicInteger ai, int newValue) {
    int currentValue;
    do {
        currentValue = ai.get();
        if (currentValue >= newValue) {
            return false;
        } 
     } while (!ai.compareAndSet(currentValue, newValue));
     return true;
}
```

From the OP's code, it would then be invoked thus:

```
AtomicInteger ai = new AtomicInteger(0);

int threadInt = ...

// Update ai atomically, but only if the current value is less than threadInt
setIfIncreases(ai, threadInt);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have Java 8, you can use a CAS-loop like this :

```
while (true) {
    int currentValue = ai.get();
    if (newValue > currentValue) {
        if (ai.compareAndSet(currentValue, newValue)) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I clicked -1, because this code causes an infinite loop if newValue <= currentValue.